# Using many useReducer to manipulate state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I'm beginner++ to React, and I encounter some issue with Hook `useReducer`.

I am fetching data from an API with a reducer (`dataFetchReducer`) with cases like this (`FETCH_INIT, FETCH_SUCCESS, FETCH_FAILURE, default`).

This reducer (`FETCH_SUCCESS`) returns the state:

```
return {
  ...state,
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false,
  data: action.payload
};
```

Plus, I initialized it:

```
const initialData = {
  isLoading: true,
  isError: false,
  data: [],
};

const [dataAPI, dispatch] = useReducer(dataReducer, initialData)
```

Now I want to use another reducer (I thought I should split reducer by action? - since I could use the `dataFetchReducer` for another component) to manipulate my state and avoid doing too much tasks.

To be precise this is a simple Todolist example. I fetched my todos, now I want to (`reset, add, remove, markAsDone`) and so on but using another reducer.

Am I doing right using another reducer (`todoReducer`) - if so, which const should I use since already declared `const [data, dispatch]` - something like `const [todos, dispatchTodos]`
but I am basically manipulating the same data ?

Hope I've been as much clear as possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think it's overkill to use another useReducer. I design my state management around entities, so for example todo is an entity so there must be one reducer to handle all the manipulation to todos.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, by naming the state and dispatch differently. But I also think that in this case, these actions are closely related so they could be handled in one reducer.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your answers then. I'll go with 1 reducer ;)